# Accessing elements

Tags: linq

Given data returned from:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ReadFile(string filename)
{
   List<List<string>> items;
   // Read entire file content into items.
   ...
   return items;
 }
```

How can I retrieve/return a specific column?

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetColumnAtIndex(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> items, int index)
{
    // THIS IS NOT WORKING...
    return (from row in items
              select row.ElementAt(index)).ToList();
}
```

Example intended use:

```
var items = ReadFile(@"testdata.csv");
var singleColumn = GetColumnAtIndex(items, 2);
```

Comment: Why isn't the supplied code working?

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? Does it return the wrong data? It sure looks right to me.

Comment: It is throwing ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException when executed.

Comment: @LabDog: that will be `row.ElementAt` throwing that. I've updated my answer with an explanation of why it might be doing it but its looking like its boiling down to the fact that you are passing bad data into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just read your comment that your problem is that you are getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` then the most likely cause for that is that some of the `List<string>` objects that make up your rows do not have enough elements to have somethign in the column you have asked for.

For example an empty row might parse to an empty `List<string>` or one with only a `""` at position 0. If you were to try to get all the entries at position 5 then whjen it got to this row it would throw that exception.

If you have `List<List<string>> items` and you want to get the `List<string>` in the 0th position you can do this:

```
List<string> innerList = items[0];
```

If you want the item that is in the 0th position of that list you can just do

```
string item = items[0][0];
```

You don't need to use linq unless I have missed what you are trying to do.

Oh, I've realised you might want the nth item from the inner list for every one of the outer lists... In that case what you have should work and indeed does in my test case:

```
List<List<string>> foo = new List<List<string>>(){new List<string>(){"1","2","3","4","5"},new List<string>(){"6","7","8","9","0"}};
var output = (from row in foo
          select row.ElementAt(2)).ToList();
output.Dump();
```

Comment: Your sample looks familiar. However, as used in function I supplied it is throwing exception.

Comment: As I said, your sample code should work and in the above context it does. Without knowing more about what is goign wrong and where its hard to say. Off the top of my head the above will fail if you try to specify a column number that does not exist in all rows (eg in the above `select row.ElementAt(20)` would throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when trying to call ElementAt to get an element that doesn't exist. Also I'm not sure if it would automatically cast `List<List<string>>` to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` but that might depend on your .NET version.

Comment: Agreed it should work but doesn't. Your sample works fine - thanks. The List<List<string>> is automatically cast as IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>. I have other methods which accept the same 'items' and functions correctly on the input.

Comment: your solution is correct. I reviewed the source data and just as you pointed out - en empty row! Yes, the empty row was causing the exception. Cleansing the source data, and rerunning, it worked nicely! Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget upvotes are also a good way of showing an answer was good as well as just accepting it. :)